# Migrate announcement items to modern news posts

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-pages, announcements, sharepoint-news

I have a lot of classic announcement items in SharePoint on premise that I would like to migrate to modern news posts in SharePoint Online.

I have found descriptions of how to modernise classic pages automatically (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages-dotnet), but these announcement list items seem to be something else than classic pages. I also have other list item types that now need to become modern pages, like FAQ items.

Does anyone know about a way to migrate classic list items to modern pages automatically?

I have access to ShareGate, so I can use that tool to fix the metadata, such as dates, authors, promoted state etc later. Often it is possible to map to another content type in ShareGate, but unfortunately I have not found any way mapping of a list item to a modern page in ShareGate either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method to migrate classic items to modern list using Microsoft migration tool, we could only migrate the announcement list to modern site.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/sharepoint-migration-supported-list-templates

For the ShareGate tool, I suggest you seek support in its [official page](https://sharegate.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwy8f6BRC7ARIsAPIXOjgFB10HoUuuVwvrbeprB7QQ-sm_AQ57HkpcK6YDHDTucYgPkYdGkmYaAg24EALw_wcB).

Comment: OK, thanks, I was not even aware of a Microsoft migration tool... I was thinking more like a solution to grab the contents of a list item and add that content to a new modern page. So I will need some way to create a new modern page automatically, add a suitable web part to it where I can put the content of the list item. (I already have a lot of C# code to work with classic list items, so I am pretty sure I can get the source content). Once I have all the pages in place I would use ShareGate to correct the metadata.